# Apache MyFaces Trinidad: <tr:column/> header Alignment tags inside a <tr:table/>

Tags: java, jsf-1.2, trinidad

I'm trying to create simple table with header align to left OR right

In case of numeric the header should align to right otherwise to left.

This is my code:

```
<tr:treeTable width="700px" var="file" value="#{bean.files}">
<tr:column>
    <f:facet name="header" >
        <tr:outputText value="File Name"/>
    </f:facet>
    <tr:outputText value="#{file.fileName}"/>
</tr:column>
<tr:column inlineStyle="text-align:right">
    <f:facet name="header" >
        <tr:outputText value="File Size"/>
    </f:facet>
    <tr:outputText value="#{file.size}"/>
    <tr:convertNumber type="number"/>
</tr:column>
```

The output from my code is that the column rows are align correctly right or left as I wanted 
BUT
the column headers are not being align to right, just to left.

My question is how can I make the column header to be align to right as well.

In the example above I need that the header File Size will be align to rigth

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `align` attribute of `tr:column`.

Example :

```
<tr:column align="right" headerText="File Name">
    <tr:outputText value="#{file.fileName}"/>
</tr:column>
```